# NA_character_ not identidied as NaN after importing it into Python with rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am using the following code inside a R magic cell:

```
%%R -o df

library(tibble)

df <- tibble(x = c("a", "b", NA))
```

However, when I run in another cell (a Python one):

```
df.isna()
```

I get

```
       x
1  False
2  False
3  False
```

In fact, the imported dataframe is

```
               x
1              a
2              b
3  NA_character_
```

How can I convert `NA_character_` to a Python `NaN`?

I have tried

```
df.replace('NA_character_', np.nan)
```

but with no success.

Comment: What's the `dtype` of the pandas column, and specifically the `NA_character` cell? The fact that you can have an `object` data type where some values are strings and some are not often trips me up, being used to R columns being vectors of one class.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @SamR. The `dtype` of the pandas column is `object`. And `type(df.iloc[2,0])` returns `rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NACharacterType`.

Comment: Oh that's cool - so it's literally using the R data type defined in C as specified in R internals. I wonder if that means it doesn't copy the data frame in memory. Anyway, I haven't set this up on my machine so I can't easily replicate but given that type is not a `numpy` type I wouldn't expect the normal `pandas` or `numpy` checks for `NaN` to work.  I should think you could do something like, `df['x'] = df['x'].apply(lambda val: np.nan if isinstance(val, rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NACharacterType) else val)` . Does that work? Obviously you'll need to `import rpy2` somewhere.

Comment: That works, @SamR! Thanks! Do you think it advisable to file a bug against `rpy2`?

Comment: I had slightly more to say than I could fit in a comment so I posted an answer but really the answer is I don't know. They may well be aware of it but they might not so I don't see that it could hurt.

Comment: I have just filed an issue against `rpy2`, @SamR: https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/983 . Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you set out in the comments, the R `NA_character_` value is not converted to `np.nan`, but has a different type, `rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NACharacterType`. In this case, the solution is simply to iterate over the column and convert this type to `np.nan`:

```py
import rpy2 # if you haven't already
df['x'] = df['x'].apply(lambda val: np.nan if isinstance(
    val, rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NACharacterType) 
    else val
)
```

As for whether this is a bug, the [changes](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/changes.html) for release 3.3.0 states:

> The value nan in pandas Series with strings is now converted to R NA (issue #668).

However, the converse does not appear to happen. I don't know whether that means it's a bug, a design decision or simply that this has not yet been implemented.